# Build App which depends upon Office Interop on Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, office-interop

I have a Windows Forms application that I'm trying to build on Azure Pipelines. Prior to trying to build on Azure I locally had COM references to locally installed Office dlls such as `Microsoft.Office.Word.dll`.

```xml
    <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Word.dll">
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <VersionMinor>7</VersionMinor>
      <VersionMajor>8</VersionMajor>
      <Guid>00020905-0000-0000-c000-000000000046</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
```

In preparation to build on Azure I have changed the references to NuGet.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" Version="15.0.4797.1003"/>
```

I now have the problem that a local debug session gives me a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly office, Version 15.0.0.0.0`, Culture=neutral...' even though the solution builds without error.

I don't seem to be able to embed the NuGet versions as I could with the locally installed versions.

I guess I could check in all of the local dlls into source control but doesn't seem like a good solution.

I also cannot find a version of `Microsoft.Office.Core.dll` anywhere on NuGet.

Does anyone know how to successfully build a Windows Forms App with Office Interop dependencies on Azure?